# How can I do the control that email is delivered?

Tags: python

I'm trying to send an email with python, but how do I find out if the email has been delivered ?

My code for sending e-mail:

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com",465)

server.login("me@gmail.com","pass")

server.sendmail("me@gmail.com","friend@gmail.com","message")

server.quit()
```

I'm trying to get a output like this :

if the mail has been sent: `OK`

if the mail could not be delivered: `BAD`

Comment: You can't really know. You can only confirm that it has been handed off to the SMTP server you're talking to. From there, it's unknown whether it is able to reach its destination. Not much different from throwing a letter into the closest postbox.

Comment: You can include a 1px image in the body and listen to GET requests on the image. If it is viewed, you'll receive a GET request.

Comment: @Vishnudev You'll only get that information much later though, and it's not guaranteed either, since email clients may block that kind of tracking pixel specifically.

Comment: You can use fail_silently=False in a try except block. But as others pointed out it doesn't really tell you if message was delivered, just if it was sent on your side.

Comment: So how do I find that it was delivered to SMTP server ? @deceze

Comment: *"This method will return normally if the mail is accepted for at least one recipient. Otherwise it will raise an exception. That is, if this method does not raise an exception, then someone should get your mail. If this method does not raise an exception, it returns a dictionary, with one entry for each recipient that was refused. Each entry contains a tuple of the SMTP error code and the accompanying error message sent by the server."* — https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail

Comment: Absolutely right @deceze. All kinds of blockers are there. Companies like mailtrack.io survive just on the basis of such a feature.

Comment: To be honestly, I didn't understand what I will write it for solving the problem. @deceze Also, I'm not interested in opening the email. I just want to make sure the mail server is running. Here, gmail is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: If you want notifications, use a service that guarantees them. ([ref](https://wordtothewise.com/2014/01/does-email-have-a-guarantee-of-delivery/)).

Even though [the newest RFC 2821](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2821) can enforce (on paper) not to drop an email, as mentioned in the comments you generally won't know when the recipient's mail-server receives the message. The only status you get back is that your SMTP server sent the message, but it could have been dropped later on in the process due to a faulty machine or just a spam filter.

There are [bounce messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message) and various other hacks to combat it such as:

- remote resources (images, iframes, etc) which if your mail client is at least a little bit secure will prevent such HTTP calls

  this is also where the web-based clients by default fail unless they *also* cut such resources from the messages and display only after you acknowledge its usage per message basis. Otherwise it'll be just a link or HTML element which will be interpreted solely by your browser (and maybe blocked by an addon) hence going through and calling home with HTTP/S request or even sending a form with data.
- Outlook's (and other clients') feature of confirming the reading of the message - which can be ignored/canceled

Emails aren't really safe nor there is any guarantee if it'll even get to the other side except that you use a more robust mail server that has been proven to work over the years which might increase the chances of delivery slightly. Nevertheless any action to let *you* know that the other side got the message depends solely on the recipient's will/security/stupidity to pass through from the machine.

I bet there's (or at least should be) some better, internal, handling of the mail messages within the same domain  (bob@hello.tld -> jim@hello.tld) which might have a higher chance of delivery + a proper bounce message, but you never know and nobody will give you an SLA or anything similar either due to the nature of emails.

Same applies even if you'd try to use an attachment doing the same calling home operation - can be prevented by antivirus, firewall, just being in a private network without (public) Internet access, downloading mails with [`POP3`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) (and reading offline), etc.